# Getting a plot of the number of papers over years in Scopus

Tags: scopus

I've a slide where there is a plot like this concerning the number of papers in the bionics field during a certain range of years (it was taken from Scopus).
Could you tell me how to get a similar plot by using Scopus please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be derived from the "Analyze search results" page in Scopus document search (you get there by searching for something e.g. [on this page](https://www.scopus.com/search/form.uri?display=basic#basic)).

[image: Scopus document search interface]"

It would not add the inset images, of course - these seem to have been added manually. Most software allowing for image manipulations would be able to handle this - in fact, it is possible even in something like PowerPoint. At the time of writing, the plot is not shaded, but a number of options including CSV export is provided, making it possible to style it to your liking.

Comment: Hello @Lodinn thank you very much for your precious answer.